# Duplication in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

This duplication can't be right. How are you supposed to do this with Gulp?

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.cjsx")
    .pipe(cjsx({bare: true}).on("error", gutil.log))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(transpile({
      formatter: "bundle"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));

  gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(transpile({
      formatter: "bundle"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-if`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if).

It could go something like this

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.{cjsx,js}") // Gets both .cjsx and .js files

    .pipe(gulpif(/[.]cjsx$/, cjsx({bare: true}).on("error", gutil.log))) // Do this only if file is a .cjsx

    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(transpile({
      formatter: "bundle"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you split this one task into two tasks, one to compile the cjsx files next to themselves (`gulp.dest("src/")`), then a second to transpile all the js files. You can have the js task depend on the cjsx if you want also, or just run in order through the cjsx.

```
gulp.task('cjsx', ....);
gulp.task('js', 'cjsx', ....);
```

e.g.

```
gulp.task("cjsx", function() {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.cjsx")
    .pipe(cjsx({bare: true}).on("error", gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src"));
});

gulp.task("js", "cjsx", function () {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(transpile({
      formatter: "bundle"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public"));
});

gulp.task("default", "js");
```